# How do I enable Hybrid Boot in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8-preview

Why is my "Enable Hybrid Boot" option grayed out in Windows 8, and how can I enable it?

[image]

Performing a `powercfg /a` results in the following error being reported:

```
Hybrid Sleep: The hypervisor does not support this standby state.
```

Comment: Ask here. you shall get an answer- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdeveloperpreviewgeneral/threads

Comment: see if it has a check mark beside it. If you want to adjust this setting, click on "Change settings that are currently unavailable"

Comment: Without any details on your computer/OS/drivers, we can only guess; can you provide some specifications?

Comment: @TomWijsman: Sure, see [here](http://www.docs.sony.com/release/specs/VPCCW27FXB_mksp.pdf).

Comment: @Mehrdad: Should indeed work, are all your drivers installed, WHQL and up-to-date?

Comment: @Mehrdad: What is the output of `powercfg /a`?

Comment: @TomWijsman: Yes, the drivers are fine. :) I'm not on Windows 8 right now, but on Windows 7 it says Standby (S3), Hibernate, Hybrid Sleep are available, and S1/S2 are unavailable. I'll run it on Windows 8 when I get the chance.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yeah, it should give useful information. It has an entry for Hybrid Boot...

Comment: @TomWijsman: It says `Hybrid Sleep: The hypervisor does not support this standby state.` Which is funny, because I don't even believe I'm running on a hypervisor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh I finally figured it out. :)

There were two steps to solving this problem:

1. I needed to uninstall Hyper-V from the Windows features (in *Programs and Features* in the Control Panel).

   This is pretty surprising, considering that I was not supposed to be running on a hypervisor, and that the script from [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/942.aspx) indeed said my baseboard manufacturer was Sony, not Microsoft.
2. I manually re-enabled hybrid boot through changing the following registry setting:

   Under

   ```
   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power
   ```

   I changed the `DWORD` named `HiberbootEnabled` to `1`.

Indeed, after the change, boot was much faster, but now it didn't give me the option to boot into another OS like before. (Instead, Windows 8 took over, and asked me what I wanted to do.)
The "shutdown" was slightly slower, though.

Answer (score 3):

“Enable Hybrid Boot” is grayed-out when it is unavailable for some reason.

From [What is Hybrid Boot in Windows 8 and how does it work?](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/152937-what-is-hybrid-boot-in-windows-8-and-how-does-it-work/) :

> To use Hybrid boot, your system must have a hibernation file and the
>   drivers must support hibernation.
>   **Hybrid boot is not available if you run Windows 8 in a Virtual Machine**.

To change Hybrid Boot in spite of it being unavailable, you will need click on "Change settings that are currently unavailable", but this will probably have no effect (or worse) :

[image]

Comment: I'm on a physical machine with a dedicated partition, and hibernation is enabled...

Comment: If the hibernation file is large enough, then what is left in the equation are the drivers, which might not be evolved enough for Windows 8. I suppose we might be talking here about disk drivers, maybe chipset driver, and maybe even the BIOS. Try to find updates on the manufacturer websites, or you may need to wait for Windows 8 to be released for good drivers to become available.

Comment: I don't understand why it would need special drivers though... it seems kinda random, considering that hibernation and hybrid boot are fine...

Comment: Every new Windows version requires driver-writers to adapt to it, which Microsoft can force by virtue of its near-monopoly. It doesn't shock me that manufacturers may not have yet come up with fully-compatible software.

Comment: It seems like that's nothing more than a guess. I could've guessed the same thing, but I was hoping for something more... thanks anyhow...

Comment: Let's call it an educated guess, please.

Comment: lol, OK, sure, whatever... I could've made the same guess myself too I guess...

Comment: No comment . . .

Comment: The driver architecture hasn't changed in Windows 8 Developer Preview, the majority of drivers thus install and run in compatibility mode for Windows 7. Only the drivers that have hard-coded checks break, but the amount of drivers that have that kind of code are small...

Comment: @TomWijsman: I was thinking about a new and yet unpublished driver-capability needed by Windows 8 in order for Hybrid Boot to be enabled.

Comment: @harrymc: See, the thing is, I really don't see why that would be necessary -- if a computer can hibernate, then it should certainly be able to do a hybrid boot, which is essentially a stripped-down version of hibernation. Hardware-wise, it doesn't seem like it would be a special feature.

Comment: I do not mean hardware, but software. In this case it can be a driver or it can also be Windows 8 itself : That Hybrid Boot wasn't (yet) in a fully-working state and so this feature was disabled by default in the Preview version. Have you tried "Change settings that are currently unavailable" ? This [article](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Enable-Disable-Hybrid-Boot-in-Windows-8-Developer-Preview-Build-8102-M3-224657.shtml) for example says that this is the way to enable it in the Developer Preview. But be warned that even if it works, this means that Hybrid Boot might still be buggy.

Comment: Again: Have you tried "Change settings that are currently unavailable" ? My conclusion of a driver is based on the assumption that this didn't work at all. If it does work, then it might not be a driver but rather Windows itself, as I described in the above comment.

Answer (score 1):

Hybrid Boot is disabled when ...

- ... you have Hibernation disabled, you can enable it by executing `powercfg /h on`.
- ... your computer doesn't support Hibernation, this is rare but possible.
- ... your drivers don't fully support Hibernation, often seen when you use Virtualize or VHD boot.

  It is best to run your OS natively and make sure all your drivers are installed, WHQL and up-to-date.

---

More explanation on why it doesn't work can be received by using `powercfg /a`.

In case you get the error `The hypervisor does not support this standby state`, you need to uninstall Hyper-V to fix this error and reboot your system which should make the grayed out option available to you...

Comment: Someone else already mentioned all of these, but it's none of them: http://superuser.com/questions/335792/how-do-i-enable-hybrid-boot-in-windows-8#comment-397671 ... hibernation works completely fine.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I don't see VHD booting nor driver support mentioned. Updating your drivers is your best bet...

Comment: Oh, that's what I meant by "a dedicated partition" -- i.e. I'm on a physical partition, not a VHD file. And no, my drivers are fine, that's not the issue...

Comment: You didn't answer my question but at least you mentioned `powercfg /a` so I'll give ya the bounty =)

Comment: @Mehrdad: I really don't have a clue, perhaps you could try to ask at the Windows 8 DP forums how you could troubleshoot that error or wait for Windows 8 to release itself. There is no information on that error yet as far as I can see so unless someone else has the exact same problem (and doesn't have an obvious reason to have that problem) I guess all you could do is fiddle with devices/drivers...

Comment: Do you reckon that installing the Hypervisor management tools might have done something to the installation, even though I'm not actually using any of the VMs? I might uninstall it and see if it makes a difference...

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yeah, that sounds pretty related and might turn the host into a VM by itself. In any case, there have been [quite some improvements to Hyper-V in Windows 8 DP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V#Future) so that makes it plausible...

Comment: And GUESS WHAT?? That turned out to be the cause! (!!!) I just uninstalled HyperV in the components and `powercfg /a` no longer reports that problem. (I have yet to test it, though.) Thanks for the help! (If you'd like, edit this into your answer and I'll accept it!)

Comment: Wait, noooooooo.... the setting is still disabled! But now `powercfg /a` says it's available! :(

Comment: @Mehrdad: Did you reboot?

Comment: LOLLL of course I did.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. Will post it in a few mins.

Answer (score -2):

It is already enabled. The boot is much faster because the system files are stored from ram to disk like in the usual hibernation, but the services are restarted on reboot. That gives the system a real fresh start with the speed of hibernation.

Comment: er, how do you know it's already enabled?

Comment: Wrong: The Hybrid Boot check-box is unchecked, so it is not enabled.

Comment: Indeed wrong, my VHD boot outperforms my Windows 7 installation but does not support Hybrid Boot. Yet, my shiny SSD laptop gets outperformed by a native install on a 6 year old laptop with a 5400 RPM drive that does support hybrid booting. Also, it's not the services that are restarted but rather the devices...